# Why does WinForms designer keep putting one of the controls' declaration inside the InitializeComponent method after I make a change in the designer?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a Winforms usercontrol with several comboboxes and other controls. In the designer.cs file there's a section at the bottom of the file where the different controls are declared. Whenever I make a change inside the design surface, the new generated .designer.cs file has one of the comboboxes' declaration moved into the InitializeComponent method. This causes a compile error because the usercontrol's partial class in the other .cs file doesn't know about the combobox anymore. So I have to manually move the declaration out of the InitializeComponent method. This odd behavior happens every time I make a change in the design surface.

I went through the designer.cs code and couldn't find what's different about this particular combobox.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is very unusual behavior.  Clearly you need to show us, provide a minimum repro so we can have a decent guess.

Comment: Provide a minimum repro how? Anyway it's not needed. Bloopy knew exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Whoever voted to close the question, I hope you have a good reason!

Comment: This is definitely another WinForms bug - anyone who's worked with WinForms must have seen it. I've battled it for years before the solution given by Bloopy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the control's `GenerateMember` property is set to false. Ensure it's set to true if you need to refer to it in code.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.